# Does Heroku do a graceful restart of its web dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running a Rails 4 production app.  I'm having issues with memory R14 type errors causing database connection issues.  As a temporary measure, I'm going to restart my web dynos.

Does Heroku "gracefully" restart so I won't lose any data? (e.g., if I'm in the middle of a database write, Heroku will "wait" to restart...)

Answer (score 2):

When restarting, Heroku will send processes running on your dynos a `SIGTERM` signal to give the processes a chance to terminate properly, then after 10 seconds will send a `SIGKILL` signal and shut down the dynos.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown